# Sum or rows of (matrix cum dataframe cum array)

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, dataframe, sum

How can I sum the below:

```
> result.vol3
       [,1]   
 [1,] 272225 
 [2,] 523750 
 [3,] 20211  
 [4,] 316165 
 [5,] 9941469
 [6,] 193755 
 [7,] 40663  
 [8,] 236746 
 [9,] 25902  
[10,] 79943  
[11,] 585326 
[12,] 129376 
                   ... till [100,]
```

Its a matrix, but within the matrix its a data.frame/array. I'm unable to compute using colSums or any other straightforward method.

Comment: DO you have a 3D  `array`?  You just do `sum(result.vol3)`

Comment: am not sure what this is, sum() is not working, if i do as.matrix, its "TRUE"

Comment: You can check the `str(result.vol3)` to get more insights

Comment: I noticed that a lot of the Very helpful people on StackOverflow are very thorough with base R functions. I have asked this q before, but it was unanswered, please suggest a way/good resource to learn base R.

Comment: str(result.vol3): List of 74
 $ : num 272225
 $ : num 523750
 $ : num 20211

Comment: sum(unlist(result.vol3))

Comment: Yes, this works @akrun  I have asked this Q before, but it was unanswered, please suggest a way/good resource to learn base R.

Comment: My advise is that create time to practise the language at least half an hour to 1 hour daily.  Make mistakes and learn from it.  If you are doing everything perfectly, you may not understand it.  I think from today's exercise, probably you got some idea why the sum didn't work and got some insights on `list` and `list` can be stored as elements in matrix

Comment: Thank You @akrun

Comment: Please do not post data into the comment section. Incorporate it into your original question (use Edit button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `matrix` have `list` elements, one easy would be to `unlist` it and get the `sum`

```
sum(unlist(result.vol3), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and somehow it worked:

result.vol3<- as.matrix(result.vol2)

result.vol4 <- as.data.table(result.vol3)

result.vol4$V1 <- as.numeric(result.vol4$V1)

sum(result.vol3)

## outputs total sum

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just compute the sum of the columns with ...

apply(result.vol3, 2, FUN = sum), where 2 specifies columns?

Comment: No, I get: Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument